# Incorporating a simple For Loop in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a quick project for my VB class and i've run into a problem. I'm new to the language so i have little idea of what i'm doing... Currently I have a very very simple program set up as an RSVP list. I have it set up with a Txt box to insert a name into a Listbox and Male / Female radio buttons with an Over 21 Check box and a Submit button to send this information to the Listbox. What i'd like to do is to somehow incorporate a loop to add a counter to a Label that when each name is added it goes up until it gets to 15 which it will then display a Messagebox. This may not have ANY use for a loop but I'm just trying to squeeze it in somewhere as it's a requirement for the assignment.

My code (Yes, I know it's poor)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub SubmitBtn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitBtn1.Click
    Dim NamesInput As String
    NamesInput = NamesTxt1.Text
    If GenderRdBtn1.Checked = False And GenderRdBtn2.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Gender")

    ElseIf GenderRdBtn1.Checked = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You Have RSVP'd as " & NamesInput)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You Have RSVP'd as " & NamesInput)
    End If
    If AgeChk1.Checked = True Then
        NamesLstBox1.Items.Add(NamesInput & " / Over 21")
    Else
        NamesLstBox1.Items.Add(NamesInput)
    End If

    If GenderRdBtn1.Checked = False And GenderRdBtn2.Checked = False Then
        NamesLstBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - there is no need for a loop here...  But, if a loop is a "functional requirement" you could just loop through the NamesLstBox Items collection each time a new name is added, iterating a counter, then set the label's value based on the count.

```
Dim Count as Integer
For Each i In NamesLstBox1.Items
    Count += 1
    If Count = 15 Then
        'display message box
    End If
Next
Label.Text = Count.ToString()
```

Again - this is a very inefficient operation, as it would make sense just to save the count each time and simply increment it.  I'd probably look for a better use of a loop somewhere else

Comment: Yes, it's very unnecessary haha but this is exactly what I was looking for so thank you very much!